# removeChild dont delete child of object

Tags: actionscript-3, actionscript

i have a movie clip called by blue_robot ,this movie clip has a child called by right_hand and i want to remove this right_hand child but remove Child don't delete it.
here my action script code:

```
var robot:blue_robot=new blue_robot();
addChild(robot);
removeChild(robot.right_hand);
```

i try this but give me error Type Error: Error #2007: Parameter child must be non-null.

Answer (score 1):

Since `right_hand` is a child of `robot`, you have to use robot's remove child method:

```
robot.removeChild(robot.right_hand);
```

This tells the `robot` instance to remove one if it's children, the object referenced in `robot.right_hand`.

Before, you were telling the parent context (`this` in your sample code) to remove the `right_hand`, but `right_hand` isn't a child of `this`, it's a child of `robot`.

---

The error you posted means that the reference `robot.right_hand` doesn't exist.

Double check you actually have an instance name or property called `right_hand` that it exists and has a value on the first frame (if timeline created) or constructor (if code created).

Comment: i try this but give me error TypeError: Error #2007: Parameter child must be non-null.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
robot.removeChild(robo.getChildByName("right_hand"));
```

But it is better to remove the right hand from inside of the blue_robot class. You should use Object Oriented functionalities. that means blue_robot have to do any thing that related to it self's by it self. so the result should be some thing like below:

```
class blue_robot extends MovieClip{
   private var myRightHand:MovieClip ;
   public blue_robot()
   {
      super();
      myRightHand = this.getChildByName("right_hand");
   }

   public function removeRightHand():void
   {
      this.removeChild(myRightHand);
   }
}
```

↑ For the blue_robot class and

```
var robot:blue_robot=new blue_robot();
addChild(robot);
robot.removeRightHand();
```

↑ To remove the right hand from the parent of the robot.